# How to access the $(this).closest('tr') inside a keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was refactoring my working code. I thought to move a common piece of code into a function and then refer that function on my keyup event. However it stopped working. Below is my code. Please help me on how I can access $(this).closest('tr') when its wrapped inside a function and I am calling this function on a keyup event of a input field. Problem is its not able to access the $(this).closest('tr') as its no more a direct part of keyup event.

```
$("#Year1_1").keyup(function () {

   calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal();

   });



function calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal() {
   var sum = 0;
   $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function (index, tr) {
   if (index != 0)
   {
   if (!isNaN(parseInt(this.value)))
   {
     sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
   }
   }
   if (index != 11) {
   $("#Total_1").val(sum);
   }
   });
   }
```

Comment: `$("#Year1_1").keyup(calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal` should expect this pointer from the event listener callback as an argument. Then you can pass it to the function.

```
$("#Year1_1").keyup(function () {
   calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal (this);
});



function calculateInvestmentTypeFirstRowTotal(element) {
   var sum = 0;
   $(element).closest('tr').find("input").each(function (index, tr) {
       if (index != 0)
       {
           if (!isNaN(parseInt(this.value)))
           {
             sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
           }
       }
       if (index != 11) {
           $("#Total_1").val(sum);
       }
    });
}
```